# NFC/RFID - Acr122u

Tags: smartcard, input-device, nfc

So I'm using the Acr122u reader as part of a project implementing Host card emulation on an Android device and need the reader for testing my application.

Picture of reader [here](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/)

I assumed at a basic level the reader would work as a simple input device, inputting data into a text-field, e.g notepad, not the case however and I'm stuck looking for software or some method of interpreting data input from the device, if anybody has any experience with this reader or ideas I would massively appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an official API provided by Advanced Card Systems Ltd., the manufacturer of your reader. A documentation about this API (how to use it, commands etc.) can be found here:
[Official ACR122U API guide on acs.com.hk](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.04.pdf)

According software: what I found on their homepage is that included drivers from Microsoft are used as this device is certified in various ways, however, on the product page you linked above there's a section called downloads with .msi driver packages for standard pc/sc (smartcard) devices.

Just give it a try, the documentation features many commands.

And to the initial mentioned "I assumed  [the reader] would work as a simple input device, inputting data into a text-field": Working with digital sensors on a bus (that could be I2C or USB) requires adressing them, they will not output data just by themselves to a specific destination (e.g. a text file). It's your job to let it do this :)